# Find the probability distribution for the number of green balls.

Tags: probability

From a box containing 4 black balls and 2 green balls, 3 balls are drawn
in succession, each ball being replaced in the box before the next draw is
made. Find the probability distribution for the number of green balls.

I want to solve this problem without presenting some complex expression (such as Bernoulli's formula), since I have seen that it is common to solve this exercise using that

Let's try

Since there is a constant substitution of balls, then the random variable $X$ (representing the number of green balls) is discrete

$X$ can take the values of $\{0, 1, 2, 3 \}$, so we must find $P(X=0)$, $P(X=1)$, $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$

Let's note that the probabilities of getting green and black are given by

$$P(G)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3} \hspace{0.4cm} P(B)=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$$

For example, we can find

$$P(X=0) = P(\{\text{Black, Black, Black}\}) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{8}{27}$$

Well, that might be one way to find the first value, but what about the rest?

Any suggestions? thank you very much!

Comment: Well, in your example, there is only one colour of ball, so it is easy. In other cases, whether through the Bernoulli formula or whatever, you need to consider that the order in which the balls come. The Bernoulli formula, I think is the simplest way. If you try on your own as a beginner, you might make mistakes at times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the balls are replaced before each draw, the probability of drawing a green ball, that is, $P(G)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$, during each draw remains identical.

The probability distribution of the number of $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ green balls drawn over $n=3$ draws is given by the mass function for a binomial random variable $X$~$B(3,\frac{1}{3})$ as follows

$$ P(k) = {n \choose k} P(G)^k \Big( 1-P(G) \Big)^{n-k} = {3 \choose k} \frac{1}{3}^k \Big( 1-\frac{1}{3} \Big)^{3-k} $$

The derivation of the mass function is rather straightforward. Lets say you want to know the probability of drawing a green ball exactly $k=2$ times over $n=3$ trials. Begin by identifying each sequence possible in which $2$ green balls are drawn:

$
\begin{array}{111}
B & G & G \\
G & B & G \\
G & G & B \\
\end{array}
$

So, there are ${n \choose k} = {3 \choose 2} = 3$ sequences in which $2$ green balls are drawn. The probability of each sequence is $P(G)P(G)P(G^C)=\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{3} \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{27}$. Now we just add the probability to itself three times.

$$ \frac{2}{27} + \frac{2}{27} + \frac{2}{27} = 3\cdot \frac{2}{27} = \frac{6}{27} = \frac{2}{9}$$